# How to add hex numbers using two's complement?

Tags: binary, hex, twos-complement

I'm taking a beginner Computer Science course at my local college and one of the parts of this assignment asks me to convert a hex number to its hex equivalent. We use an online basic computer to do this that takes specific inputs specific inputs.

So according to my Appendix, when I type in a certain code it is supposed to "add the bit patterns [ED] and [09] as though they were two's complement representations." When I type the code into the system, it gives an output of F6... but I have no idea how it got there.

I understand how adding in two's complement works and I understand how to add two normal hex numbers, but when I add 09 (which is supposed to be the hex version of two's complement 9) and ED (which is supposed to be the hex version of two's complement -19), I get 10 if adding in two's complement or 162 if adding in hex.

Comment: How do you get `1F2` from `09 + ED`?

Comment: Oops, I mean 162.                                         9 + D(13) = 22, carry the two. 0 + E(14) + 2 = 16, carry the 1. So 162


Some guy explains it here: http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/66714.html

Comment: `22` is decimal. It's `16` in hex, so you carry the one.

Comment: Sheesh, sorry this is a mess I accidentally hit "Add Comment" while I was writing it and realized my math mistake. But 162 =/= F6 still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you're just confusing yourself. Stop converting. This is all in hexadecimal:

```
  ED
+ 09
----

D + 9 = 16    // keep the 6 and carry the 1

  1
  ED
+ 09
----
   6

1 + E = F

  ED
+ 09
----
  F6
```

Regarding the first step, using 0x to denote hex numbers so we don't get lost:

```
0xD = 13,
0x9 = 9, 
13 + 9 = 22, 
22 = 0x16
```

therefore

```
0xD + 0x9 = 0x16
```

---

Gotta run, but just one more quick edit before I go.

```
D + 1 = E
D + 2 = F
D + 3 = 10  (remember, this is hex, so this is not "ten")
D + 4 = 11
...
D + 9 = 16
```

Comment: What happens when you convert `22` from decimal to hexadecimal?

Comment: Woah wait so any time we add two hexadecimal numbers we get a decimal answer that we have to convert to hexadecimal?

Comment: No. You don't convert it at **all**. `0xD + 0x9 = 0x16`. There are **no** decimal values required. That's why I hesitated to put that part in. Gotta run, I'll check back in an hour or so.

Comment: Ohh, your last edit made it all make sense now! So what does this all have to do with two's complement?

Comment: I started to add another edit to go into 2's complement, but it was longer than the rest of the answer. How about if I just say that `0xED` is the 2's complement representation of `-19 decimal`. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93274/discussion-between-guy-and-beaker).